# How do I create a column using strings retrieved from another column on python?

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I am trying to read information from a column in my csv file and use it to create a new column. Please help

I imported the csv file and printed the first 10 rows (+ header) but now I would like to  create a column for the years in the title column.

````
```
import csv
from itertools import islice
from operator import itemgetter
#opening the CSV file
with open('/home/raymondossai/movies.csv', mode ='r')as file:
#reading the CSV file
    csvFile = csv.reader(file)
#displaying the contents of the CSV file
    for row in islice(csvFile, 11): # first 10 only
        print(row)
```
````

Result:

```
['movieId', 'title', 'genres']
['1', 'Toy Story (1995)', 'Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy']
['2', 'Jumanji (1995)', 'Adventure|Children|Fantasy']
['3', 'Grumpier Old Men (1995)', 'Comedy|Romance']
['4', 'Waiting to Exhale (1995)', 'Comedy|Drama|Romance']
['5', 'Father of the Bride Part II (1995)', 'Comedy']
['6', 'Heat (1995)', 'Action|Crime|Thriller']
['7', 'Sabrina (1995)', 'Comedy|Romance']
['8', 'Tom and Huck (1995)', 'Adventure|Children']
['9', 'Sudden Death (1995)', 'Action']
['10', 'GoldenEye (1995)', 'Action|Adventure|Thriller']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` to extract the year from the `title`:

```py
rows = [
    ["movieId", "title", "genres"],
    ["1", "Toy Story (1995)", "Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy"],
    ["2", "Jumanji (1995)", "Adventure|Children|Fantasy"],
    ["3", "Grumpier Old Men (1995)", "Comedy|Romance"],
    ["4", "Waiting to Exhale (1995)", "Comedy|Drama|Romance"],
    ["5", "Father of the Bride Part II (1995)", "Comedy"],
    ["6", "Heat (1995)", "Action|Crime|Thriller"],
    ["7", "Sabrina (1995)", "Comedy|Romance"],
    ["8", "Tom and Huck (1995)", "Adventure|Children"],
    ["9", "Sudden Death (1995)", "Action"],
    ["10", "GoldenEye (1995)", "Action|Adventure|Thriller"],
]

import re

pat = re.compile(r"\((\d{4})\)")

for movie_id, title, genres in rows[1:]:
    year = pat.search(title)
    print([movie_id, title, genres, year.group(1) if year else "N/A"])
```

Prints:

```py
['1', 'Toy Story (1995)', 'Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy', '1995']
['2', 'Jumanji (1995)', 'Adventure|Children|Fantasy', '1995']
['3', 'Grumpier Old Men (1995)', 'Comedy|Romance', '1995']
['4', 'Waiting to Exhale (1995)', 'Comedy|Drama|Romance', '1995']
['5', 'Father of the Bride Part II (1995)', 'Comedy', '1995']
['6', 'Heat (1995)', 'Action|Crime|Thriller', '1995']
['7', 'Sabrina (1995)', 'Comedy|Romance', '1995']
['8', 'Tom and Huck (1995)', 'Adventure|Children', '1995']
['9', 'Sudden Death (1995)', 'Action', '1995']
['10', 'GoldenEye (1995)', 'Action|Adventure|Thriller', '1995']
```

Comment: i think using regex is actually way cleaner than my approach, but could you please explain the '\\(' at the start and '\\)' at the end of the expression? i'm not really used to working with re.

Comment: @maxxel_ `(` and `)` have special meanings in regex pattern (it marks a *group*). So to match literal character `(` and `)` you need to escape it with `\`

Answer (score 0):

you should definetly use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for this, it's way easier to work with tables and way cleaner too.

try to read in the csv file like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/home/raymondossai/movies.csv')
```

the df object is basically your csv table represented as an object in python.

for having the year as an extra column you could use the str.split() method since the year always follows after a ' (' expression:

```
# get the 4 characters of the year (first 4 characters after the ' (' expression)
df['Year'] = df['title'].str.split(pat=' (', expand=True)[1][:4].astype(int)
```

Comment: I am now using Pandas to import the csv file. It is indeed more convenient however your code doesn't solve my problem. I get an unterminated sub pattern error

Comment: @RaymondOssai i edited the code, should work now